# "Local variable referenced before assignment" Django error

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I have no idea what may cause this issue. The only change I've made was add the loginquiredmixins to my class-based views.

Once I started stylising the login page I seem to have broken something, but I have no idea what exactly, which is a weird idea to have, what issue could CSS or some HTML cause, right?

I tried to assign the variables before the `if` statement and set it to `null` but that seems not to work properly as it throws an error regardless. I am using the basic django authentication system.

The exact error I am getting is - `local variable 'course' referenced before assignment.

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/login

Django Version: 3.0.7
Python Version: 3.7.3
Installed Applications:
['mainpage.apps.MainpageConfig',
 'quiz.apps.QuizConfig',
 'courses.apps.CoursesConfig',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\m\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda33\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 34, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\m\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda33\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 115, in _get_response
    response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
  File "C:\Users\m\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda33\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 113, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\m\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda33\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 71, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\m\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda33\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\mixins.py", line 52, in dispatch
    return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\m\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda33\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 97, in dispatch
    return handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "H:\Learning Development Platform\learningplatform\courses\views.py", line 26, in get
    lesson_qs = course.lesson.filter(slug=lesson_slug)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /accounts/login
Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lesson'
```

Here's my models.py file:

```
from django.contrib.auth import decorators
from django.db import models
from django.db.models.fields import SlugField
from django.urls import reverse


class Course(models.Model):
  slug = models.SlugField()
  title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
  description = models.TextField()


  def __str__(self) -> str:
      return self.title


  def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('courses:detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})

  @property
  def lessons(self):
    return self.lesson_set.all().order_by('position') # syntax for foreignkey object


class Lesson(models.Model):
  slug = models.SlugField()
  title = models.CharField(max_length=120)
  course = models.ForeignKey(Course, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
  position = models.IntegerField()
  video_url = models.CharField(max_length=200)

  def __str__(self) -> str:
      return self.title


  def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse(
      'courses:lesson-detail', 
      kwargs={
        'course_slug': self.course.slug,
        'lesson_slug': self.slug
        }
    )
```

And my views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, View
from .models import Course, Lesson
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin


class CourseListView(ListView):
    model = Course


class CourseDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Course


class LessonDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):

    def get(self, request, course_slug, lesson_slug, *args, **kwargs):

      course_qs = Course.objects.filter(slug=course_slug)
      if course_qs.exists():
        course = course_qs.first()

      lesson_qs = course.lesson.filter(slug=lesson_slug)
      if lesson_qs.exists():
        lesson = lesson_qs.first()

      context = {
        'object': lesson
      }

      return render(request, 'courses/lesson_detail.html', context)
```

Comment: You only set `course` to `course_qs.first()` if `course_qs.exists()`. Otherwise it's undefined/has no assigned value by the time the line `course.lesson.filter(slug=lesson_slug)` is reached. Did you mean `Course`? Python is case sensitive. Or, do you maybe need to give `course` a dummy value at the start of the function?

Comment: The purpose of the quearysets is to find the first lessons on a position value I set in django admin. I tried assigning None values to the course and lesson but that seems not to work at all. From the stackoverflow issues I went through that was mostly the solution that fixed it for others, it does not fix it for me I am afraid...

Answer (score 0):

How much i understand...

in your "LessonDetailView" Class => In "get" method

Change this

```
lesson_qs = course.lesson.filter(slug=lesson_slug)
```

to

```
lesson_qs = course.objects.filter(slug=lesson_slug)
```

Then This Error will be solved:

Exception Type: AttributeError at /accounts/login

Exception Value: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lesson'

Comment: Thank you for your help but that seems to not make it work I am afraid. The main issue is that the Course variable is referenced before the assignment. It normally works, but once I add the loginrequiredmixins the error appears, also when I try to add the mixin to only one class, the login works just fine but the logout seems to be an issue then.

Comment: How much i know Django, loginrequiredmixins just work as Login_Required decorators. ..... If you want to get rid of loginrequiredmixins (as you are adding permission login required to your whole class) then you can use decorator include in your URL pattern instead of include. or your can also use a decorator login_required for your class.

Comment: method_decorator(login_required , name="dispatch") # like this

Comment: I will give this a shot, I had been thinking of using the login_required decorator. Will post the results soon. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Seems like I have fixed it.

For some reason, adding the whole url that is responsible for the login_url solved the issue. The login_redirect was not working properly as it was redirecting a view that was causing the issue.

Thank you for all your help!